# Do installing a Managed Package (listed in AppExchange) via Salesforce CLI, create a License & Lead in package developer's LMA org?

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, scratch-org, package-install, lma

Can anyone confirm if this is the case. Though I don't really think this should be allowed, but I'm suspecting random licenses occurring and it's a hunch that they are being generated because it is being installed in a Scratch org.

But Scratch org only lives a maximum for 7 days, I mean ultimately it will convolute the business org of an ISV with too much unneeded data licenses.

So can anyone confirm if I'm thinking correct and that LMA will find and create a License for any package installed in a scratch org.

And if Yes, is there an easy way to identify if a Lead or License is from a Scratch org?

Comment: If you suspect it may be doing so, why not try with your own scratch org to confirm? If it is, contact partner support, and if not, then something else is going on. It shouldn't be creating LMA entries any more than a sandbox should.

Comment: Not familiar with SalesforceDX development myself :( ..

Comment: Install DX, link it to your prod org, create a scratch org, and install. If you want, I'd be glad to spend a moment installing your package, but you'd have to check the LMA yourself, obviously.

Comment: I guess it's time for me to grab DX Badge in Trailhead :). I'll update this post with my test result then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Installing a package into a scratch org WILL create a license record in the LMA and a Lead Record.

The Lead name will be User User. I not not have a current one to check the org Status on the license, but the Sandbox checkbox will be true

**Note** Scratch orgs can live for up to 30 days

Comment: Yes. I was able to produce the same behavior in my testing with scratch orgs.